# Spring Cloud Stream - Functional Supplier is not polling

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

In Spring Cloud Stream, I used the functional model and created a Supplier to generateEvents.  As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources), I expect that this supplier will get invoked on a scheduled basis, but that's not happening. It gets invoked once upon bean creation, and never again.  I'd appreciate any help in figuring out why.

EventSource.java (Supplier):

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class EventSource {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> generateEvents() {
        log.debug("creating an event to publish to Kafka");
        return () -> "Hi I'm an event";
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: generateEvents
    stream:
      bindings:
        generateEvents-out-0:
          destination: eventsTopic
```

I know I'm connecting to Kafka, because the topic `eventsTopic` gets created upon startup.  The Cloud Stream app stays up, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just tested it and all works as expected. There are also many tests to validate. Perhaps you can post a small project that reproduces the issue somewhere in GithUb where we can tale a look?

Comment: The `debug` log in the bean definition will only be called once; you need to move it inside the lambda if you want to log on every event.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar issue where the Supplier does not seem to be called!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code and I hope you solve the problem:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class EventSource {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> generateEvents() {
        return () -> {
            log.debug("creating an event to publish to Kafka");
            return "Hi I'm an event";
        };
    }
}
```